# Reuse security credentials from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm in Java using JBoss and I have an environment where I'm creating an HttpServlet, and from within that HttpServlet I would like to get information from another URL using an HttpsURLConnection.  In order to connect to my HttpServlet, the user must be authenticated (which is working fine).  This is also true to connect to the next HttpsURLConnection, and the authentication is the same.  I was wondering if there is a way to pass the security credentials (username and password) from the HttpServletRequest that I receive to the HttpsURLConnection that I create.  Right now I'm using just an admin account that I create and hard coding the username and password, but this isn't good long term as I do auditing of this account and I want to know the original user who accessed this data, and not the intermediate admin user.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815149/how-to-communicate-share-a-session-between-pages-over-http-and-https

Comment: It depends on how the user is authenticated, but what you describe is not generally possible.

Comment: Right now we're using BASIC authentication, but in the future, we might use DIGEST or some other method.

Comment: In case of Basic authentication, you can of course extract the username and password from the Authentication header. With digest authentication, you can not.